# Is it possible to use a PCIe NVMe SSD on an older Lynnfield/P55 chipset motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, pci-express, nvme

I have:

1. A PCIe NVMe SSD
2. An NVMe to PCIe x4 [adapter card](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboard-Accessory/HYPER_M2_X4_MINI_CARD/specifications/).
3. An old [Asus P7P55D-E motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55DE/).

I have the PCIe x4 card sitting in the x16 slot, which I think is fine by the PCIe standard. The drive does not show up in bios.

The adapter card states "Support ASUS Z170/H170/X99/Z97/H97/B85 series motherboard models" chipsets. As far as I can tell the motherboard is a P55.

Is there some way to use the NVMe card or do I need to replace the motherboard?

Comment: The drive does not show up in the BIOS firmware since the BIOS has no idea how to handle the NVME protocol. It might still work perfectly fine if you can boot an OS which does NVME support. (Note that this means that you cannot use the NVME disk to boot from with this motherboard, you would need an motherboard with up to date firmware. And probaly with UEFI instead of BIOS).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and no. Yes, you should be able to use the drive for storage with the adapter without any issues.

But **you will not be able to use it as a boot drive**. According to [Intel, one of the companies that designed NVMe](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/solid-state-drives/000005967.html), you must have a Z97 or more recent chipset to use it as a boot drive.

Answer (score 1):

In order to directly boot from a device, the BIOS/UEFI must have access to a suitable driver. This is seperate to the driver used by the operating system during normal operation.

Most add-in storage controller cards have "option roms", these essentially add a driver to the BIOS/UEFI allowing it to boot from the add-in card. So you can add a SCSI, SATA, SAS etc controller to a system and boot from it. Be aware that there are different types of option rom for legacy BIOS and UEFI, some cards will support both while others may only support one or the other.

M.2 NVMe SSDs do not come with option roms. On a board with a M.2 slot this is generally not a problem, the UEFI implementation will have a NVME driver out of the box. However if you use an adapter card to connect a M.2 NVME SSD to an older system then it will generally not be directly bootable.

There exists a third party bootloader called "clover", which apparently can be booted of a device that is supported (such as a USB stick), load a NVME driver and then boot the system off a NVME SSD. Googling "clover boot NVME" finds a number of articles on setting it up.

It is also possible in some cases to modify the BIOS to add NVME support.